# Запрет на скачивание шаблона в .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

В папке templates у меня лежат шаблоны (.tpl). Когда из браузера прописываешь путь к шаблону, то он скачивает его. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь не мог скачивать шаблоны.

Я залил в папку templates файл настроек .htaccess и прописал в нём `deny from all`. Но всё равно, если прописать в браузере ссылку на шаблон, то браузер качает данный шаблон.

Как сделать так, чтобы у пользователя не было доступа к шаблону (чтобы он не мог его скачивать)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так (ненужные расширения сотрите)

```
<Files ~ "\.dat$|\.inc$|\.bak$|\.old$|\.log|\.tpl$"> 
Order allow,deny 
Deny from all 
</Files>
```

Comment: ReinRaus, Ваш ответ очень помог, спасибо

Comment: @intro, всегда рад помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Однозначно

```
Deny from all
```

Либо есть косяки в настройке Apache.